# Heroku not showing log messages created during scheduled tasks

Tags: php, logging, heroku, lumen

I'm using Heroku to host a Lumen app. I've setup the logging to send messages to stdout:

```
// bootstrap/app.php
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
    /** @var Monolog\Logger $monolog */
    $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
});
```

I've tested this works by adding a log message to the schedule function

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    \Log::info('Running cronjobs.');

    $schedule
        ->command('update:daily')
        ->timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
        ->everyMinute();
}
```

The Heroku logs show:

```
Jan 19 09:42:15 service app/scheduler.4140: [2018-01-19 17:42:14] lumen.INFO: Running cronjobs. [] [] 
Jan 19 09:42:15 service app/scheduler.4140: Running scheduled command: '/app/.heroku/php/bin/php' artisan update:daily > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

However the `update:daily` command has a number of log messages inside it and none of them are showing up.

I thought this might be because of the `> '/dev/null'` so I tried adding `->sendOutputTo('php://stdout')` and `->sendOutputTo(base_path('storage/logs/cronjobs.log'))` to the scheduled task but neither works.

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C heroku-nginx.conf -l storage/logs/cronjobs.log public/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses the `> '/dev/null'` when you do not call `->sendOutputTo()`. I couldn't figure out an appropriate way to use the `->sendOutputTo()` function to send to stdout.

What I did to fix this issue was change the `->command()` function to a `->call(function(){})` function and executed the same single line of code the terminal command could have called. When laravel calls a Closure, it does **not** dump the output to `> '/dev/null'`.

Answer (score 1):

Ethan is right with his observation regarding `> '/dev/null'`. As Heroku collects logs from `stdout` and `stderr` - scheduled tasks are not being logged correctly.

**Luckily there's a simple workaround**: log to a file, and output it's content into `stdout`. Heroku will then be able to log everything, whether using its native logging or using an add-on like LogDNA, Papertrail, etc.

Given that you're logging to a `single` channel in `logging.php`, into the file `storage/logs/laravel.log`, replace your scheduler command `php artisan schedule:run` with the following:

`touch ./storage/logs/laravel.log; tail -f ./storage/logs/laravel.log & php artisan schedule:run`

**What it does?**

1. Makes sure a log file exists. If it didn't - the following command will fail
2. Tails the log file, so its content is outputted to `stdout`
3. Starting the Laravel scheduler

**The advantage of using this method** is that you don't need to change your code, rather the configuration and the environment, so if you're running the app on other platforms - it won't change the way they work/log.